# Download website links having specific elements around

Tags: wget, httrack

I need to mirror recursively some site wallpaper images having a specific markup around, like:

```
<div class="wb_more">
Original Resolution: <a href="//site.com/download/space_planet_sky_94434/4800x2700">4800x2700</a><br>
Views: <a href="/download/last">96661</a>
</div>
```

but not others, like:

```
<div class="wd_resolution">
<span class="wd_res_cat">Fullscreen</span>
<span class="wd_res_cat_raz"><a class="wb_res_select" href="//site.com/download/space_planet_sky_94434/1600x1200">1600x1200</a>
...
</span>
...
</span>
</div>
```

Note, the URLs are the same, except for the resolutions, but the resolutions of the originals might vary, so only the markup around makes the difference, like preceeding the link with a text like `Original Resolution:`.

Is there a solution for this using wget or httrack or some other tool?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with **scraping** tools like [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/).
You can parse html response with css, xpath, regex or others to get links matching yours rule.

I think it is preferable to make **scraper** per site.
For example, for the first one:

```
import scrapy

class imageLink(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'imageLink'
    
    # Here the list of url to start scraping
    start_urls = ['https://images.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        # Get the link
        link = response.css('div.wb_more > a ').xpath('@href')
        # Make a callback to save the image
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.save_image)
   
    def save_image(self, response):
        link = response.url
        # Guess the filename from the link
        # space_planet_sky_94434
        filename = link.split('/')[5]
        # Save the image
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

If the site has pagination for images you can add a callback to parse with the link of the next page.

I didn't test the code.

Comment: Could you please provide an example? I have not much experience with python, BTW.

Comment: I added some code to help you to start. But I think if you don't have so much experiences with python, it is may be to hard to use scrapy. BTW, one of my first experience in python was to make scrapper to automatize some task (But scrapy didn't exist, so I did it from scratch :D).

Comment: In my case, I need to do some new functions and I have not much experience with python. So now I'm stuck with a strange behavior when it ignores some class function body (I know the indentation is correct).

Comment: I have pagination issues, meaning it declares some number of pages and it has less or more. Is there a technique to request pages until some condition is met in the request callback using `yield`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a normal `wget` and use regex on it (with `sed` or `perl` for example) 
And then download the link you obtain (wget can do it)

A basic script will look like that

```
wget [URL] -o MyPage.html
./GetTheFlag.pl -html MyPage.html > WallPaperList.txt
wget -i WallPaperList.txt #here you can put your image where you want
```

With the GetFlag.pl looks like

```
use warnings; 
use strict; 
use Getopt::Long;
my $Url;
my $MyPage;
GetOptions("html=s" => \$MyPage);
open(FILE,$MyPage);
my $content=FILE;
my @urls=($content =~ //gi) #insert here a regex depending on the flags around
foreach my $i (@urls) {
    print "$i\n";
}
```

For example if your url are `<a href="url">New Wallpaper</a>` the regex will be

```
 =~ /<a href="(\w+)">New Wallpaper</a>
```

care about `\w` it misses some character that can't be used in var name as `-`

Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Well, some simple example would be necessary for the start, I have no idea of how to do it.

Comment: BTW, the criterion is outside of the <a> element.

Comment: Sorry for being that late. Was new to stack overflow at the moment. Can you provide the type of marker to create a regex example.